# How to use helm-etags with a TAGS file that includes other tag files?

Tags: emacs, etags, emacs-helm

I used exuberant ctags to create my tags file with the `--etags-include` option and i see the included tags file in the main TAGS file.  But when i try to use `helm-etags`, it doesn't dig into the included tags file.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Ask on the helm list if you don't get an answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/emacs-helm

Comment: [done](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/emacs-helm/tags/emacs-helm/8mlEVyAwpEY/PvEv8Tt6NOkJ), thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

you may try 
https://github.com/jixiuf/helm-etags-plus
 it support multiple tag files.
(setq tags-table-list '("/path/of/TAGS1" "/path/of/TAG2"))